# MailChimp API: Batch Check Subscription Status

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

What's the best way to check a batch of email addresses and whether or not they are subscribed to a particular list? My current method is making an API call for each email address, but this becomes very slow when the count becomes > 50.

I'm using V2.0, using PHP methods since I'm developing on CakePHP.

```
 //Determine MailChimp Subscription
 $args = array(
    'id' => $this->apiKeys['mailchimp_list_ID'],
    'emails' => array(1 => array('email' => $customer['User']['username']))
 );
 $mailChimpQuery = $this->mailChimp('member-info', $args);
 $mailChimpStatus = ($mailChimpQuery['success_count'] == 1 ? 1 : 0);
 $customer['Customer']['subscribed'] = $mailChimpStatus;
```

The `mailChimp` call in another Controller is:

```
public function mailChimp($action, $args=array()) {

        $args['apikey'] = $this->apiKeys['mailchimp_api'];
        $url = 'https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/' . $action .'.json';

        if (function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_setopt')){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        } else {
            $json_data = json_encode($args);
            $result    = file_get_contents($url, null, stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'protocol_version' => 1.1,
                    'user_agent'       => 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0',
                    'method'           => 'POST',
                    'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                    "Connection: close\r\n" .
                    "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
                    'content'          => $json_data,
                    ),
                )));
        }

        return  $result ? json_decode($result, true) : false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I came up with my own solution:

1. Create an array of all the email addresses in the database
2. Create a for-loop that takes segments of 50 email addresses from that array and runs a batch check using **member-info** (https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php)
3. Manipulate the return array from the API call to extract only the email address and whether or not it's subscribed to the list.
4. Within the for-loop, add each 50 email addresses return values into a new array and then by the end of it; you'll have an array of all the email addresses in your database with a corresponding true/false value depending on whether or not they are subscribed to the list.

Good luck!